# Invalid group of use function using nested JSON_ARRAYAGG()

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have the following simple query

```
select 
    jrt.threadId,
    JSON_ARRAYAGG(
        JSON_OBJECT(
        'roundId',jrr.roundId,
        'bets', JSON_ARRAYAGG(
                    JSON_OBJECT(
                        'betId', bets.betId,
                        'amount', bets.amount
                    )
            )
        )
    ) as rounds
from threads jrt
    left join rounds jrr on jrt.threadId = jrr.threadId
            left join bets on jrr.roundId= bets.roundId
group by jrt.threadId
```

Which substantially works if I remove `bets`  from the first `JSON_OBJECT` key-values.

I am having a rough time understanding the exact reason of the error, as it is little suggestive.

```
{"code":"ER_INVALID_GROUP_FUNC_USE","errno":1111}
```

The query also works if I use the`JSON_ARRAY` aggregate function on `bets`, instead of `JSON_ARRAYAGG`.

If `Bets` is an aggregate, why is `JSON_ARRAYAGG` throwing an error?

Comment: do you have some sample data for your query? besides yourquery ha s a bug bseides the group function there is a comma too much in th json_object for bets

Comment: Aggregate functions CANNOT be nested.

Answer (score 0):

Nested JSON_ARRAYAGG is not allowed instead you have to use nested query. I have modified your query following should work

```
select 
            jrt.threadId,
            JSON_ARRAYAGG(
                JSON_OBJECT(
                'roundId',jrr.roundId,
                'bets',( select  JSON_ARRAYAGG(
                            JSON_OBJECT(
                                'betId', bets.betId,
                                'amount', bets.amount
                            ) from threads jrt
            left join rounds jrr on jrt.threadId = jrr.threadId
                    left join bets on jrr.roundId= bets.roundId
                    ))
                )
            ) as rounds
        from threads jrt
            left join rounds jrr on jrt.threadId = jrr.threadId
                    left join bets on jrr.roundId= bets.roundId
        group by jrt.threadId
```

if some can optimize it further let me know